# mdb_autocomplete drop down does not close on click event

Tags: javascript, typescript, dropdown

In certain cases, usually after values have been cached from an initial search, I cannot get the mdb_autocomplete drop down to close on a single click. I often have to double click on my selection to get it to close. I am dynamically populating the values in the drop down via an Ajax call to a service method via and controller action method that searches the active directory for the first 30 name values. No call back occurs until a user enters at least 3 values into the mdb_autocomplete selection box.  The callback and population of the drop down is working very well, but the click event following the selection of a value often will not close the dropdown.  Additionally, we are being forced to use mdb boostrap over the normal bootstrap library.  I have included the view, service, and typescript code that is being used to generate and populate the drop down.

View:

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="font-weight-bold" for="RequestorSearchInput">Requestor</label>
            <input type="text" id="RequestorSearchInput" name="RequestorSearchInput" class="form-control mdb-autocomplete" />
            <span id="loading_data_icon"></span>
        </div>
```

Service Method:

```
    public List<string> GetRequestor(string aRequestor)
    {
        IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, string>> requestorNames;
        using (ActiveDirectoryService service = new ActiveDirectoryService(<LDAP Domain Name>))
        {
            string[] propertiesToLoad = new string[] { "displayName" };
            //requestorNames = service.SearchByPartialUsername(aRequestor, propertiesToLoad).Take(30).Union(service.SearchBySurname(aRequestor, propertiesToLoad).Take(30));
            requestorNames = service.SearchBySurname(aRequestor, propertiesToLoad).Take(30);
        }
        return requestorNames.SelectMany(x => x.Values).Where(y => y.IndexOf(",", StringComparison.Ordinal) >= 0).Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

TypeScript:

```
private handleRequestorSearch() {
    let options: string[] = new Array();

    // @ts-ignore
    let searchval = $("#RequestorSearchInput").val().length;

    if (searchval >= 3) {
        $.ajax({
            url: main.getControllerHREF("GetRequestor", "Search"),
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                requestor: $("#RequestorSearchInput").val()
            },
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (names) {

                $.each(names, function () {
                    options.push(this);
                });

                // @ts-ignore
                $("#RequestorSearchInput").mdb_autocomplete({
                    data: options
                }).select(function () {
                    $("#RequestorSearchInput").focus;
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```